# How to get column names in a SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a function (remote database, without models in my app), I am making a request to it. Is it possible to get the column names using `query` rather than `execute`?

```
session = Session(bind=engine)
data = session.query(func.schema.func_name())
```

I am getting an array of strings with values, how do I get the keys? I want to generate a dict.

When I make a request with an `execute`, the dictionary is generated fine.

```
data = session.execute("select * from schema.func_name()")
result = [dict(row) for row in data]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
keys = session.execute("select * from schema.func_name()").keys()
```

Or try accessing it after the query:

```
data = session.query(func.schema.func_name()).all()
data[0].keys()
```

You can also use: `data.column_descriptions`

Documention:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html

Comment: This (with query) returns RMKeyView([])... :(
But with execute all keys are returned.

Comment: Used ```all()```?

Comment: Yes. I also tried running data = session.execute(func.schema.func_name().all() and that returned the key, but it came exactly like the function name RMKeyView(['func_name_1']).

Comment: Try ```data.column_descriptions```

Comment: [{'name': None, 'type': NullType(), 'aliased': False, 'expr': <sqlalchemy.sql.functions.Function at 0x7fa296371160; func_name_1>, 'entity': None}]

Get back only this without all()

After calling date.all(), a list of strings without field names is returned, I don't know why, example:
[('(OK, name, f,)',), ('(OK, id, f,)',)')]
Is this normal, should the data be returned like this?

Comment: Yes,
name should be the column name.